# Unable to start zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I went through full disk space(100%) issue due to which core got corrupted. As I have googled I have removed all snapshots from `version-2` and `datalog/version-2`.

Right now `/var/zookeeper` having only `myid` file and `__backup` folder.

While I am trying to start zookeeper I am getting below error

```
2016-06-12 12:43:36,512 [myid:4] - ERROR [main:FileTxnSnapLog@210] - Parent /search/cluster1/overseer/queue missing for /search/cluster1/overseer/queue/qn-0000000288
2016-06-12 12:43:36,514 [myid:4] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeer@453] - Unable to load database on disk
java.io.IOException: Failed to process transaction type: 1 error: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /search/cluster1/overseer/queue
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:153)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:417)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:409)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:111)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /search/cluster1/overseer/queue
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.processTransaction(FileTxnSnapLog.java:211)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:151)
        ... 6 more
2016-06-12 12:43:36,514 [myid:4] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@89] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run quorum server
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:454)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:409)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:111)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to process transaction type: 1 error: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /search/cluster1/overseer/queue
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:153)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:417)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /search/cluster1/overseer/queue
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.processTransaction(FileTxnSnapLog.java:211)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:151)
        ... 6 more
```

Could you please help me with this fix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently your zookeeper seems to be in an inconsistent state where it's trying to find a missing node. Look in the zoo.cfg file to see if your ZooKeeper's dataDir setting are consistent.

Or this could be a know issue of Zookeeper.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1813